# Do most women who lose their virginity between 15 and 19 years of age wish they had waited longer?

Tags: sexuality

EnkiVillage writes in [Weird Sex Facts](http://www.enkivillage.com/weird-sex-facts.html):

> Most women who lose their virginity between ages fifteen and nineteen actually wish they had waited a bit longer.

Is that claim mainly propaganda to get teenagers to have sex later or is it true?

Comment: Why can't it be **both**? :)

Comment: True if they did it with me.  :(